# How to schedule executions of a Python script on Azure

Tags: python, azure

What would be the best approach to run scheduled python script on azure which is making some calculation and storing result as CSV in Azure Blobs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution to this problem is to create an Azure function with a timer trigger. You can configure the timer to execute as often as you want.

Here's an example for the timer configuration, which will execute the script `timerfunc.py` every working day at 12PM:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "timerfunc.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 12 * * 1-5"
    }
  ]
}
```

an example for `timerfunc.py`:

```
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    logging.info('Function executed!')
```

---

You can find more examples of Python code, as well as information on how to configure the timer, at the following documentation page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python