# How can I upload a .py file to onedrive and run the script on a schedule?

Tags: python, sharepoint

I have a python script that extract data from a website and I want to run it on a regular schedule such as every day at 12:00. How can I save this .py file somewhere on onedrive and set it up to run on my schedule so that my PC does not need to be on and others who also have access to the SharePoint site can edit the script when required?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to schedule executions of a Python script on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279478/how-to-schedule-executions-of-a-python-script-on-azure)